# Class NameError: name 'var' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

```
class Gui():
    var = None
    def refreshStats(args):
        print(str(var))
clas = Gui()
clas.refreshStats()
```

Trace

```
File "sample.py", line 5, in refreshStats
    print(str(var))
NameError: name 'var' is not defined.
```

Why?

Comment: You have made `var` a class attribute belonging to the `Gui` class, so you'd have to access it as `Gui.var`.

Comment: You're missing a `self` parameter on `refreshStats`, by the way (unless you intend `args` to be the class)

Comment: @cricket_007: nope, that would cause an error. technically the OP just renamed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your variables to be visible within the scope of your class functions, pass self into every class function and use your class variables as `self.var` such as this:

```
class Gui():
    var = None
    def refreshStats(self, args):
        print(str(self.var))
clas = Gui()
clas.refreshStats()
```

If you want to use this as an instance variable (only for this instance of the class) as opposed to a class variable (shared across all instances of the class) you should be declaring it in the `__init__` function:

```
class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = None
    def refreshStats(self, args):
        print(str(self.var))
clas = Gui()
clas.refreshStats()
```

Comment: And what if the class variable was intentional?

Comment: You also should be initializing your class variables in an init function. see edits

Comment: That's called an instance variable, not a class variable

Comment: Quite right, I hope my edits have clarified things

Answer (score 1):

make method inside class either classmethod or instance method then you can access all class instance property or varable inside method if method is instance method or if class method then class property you can access inside method

```
class A():
     a = 0

     def aa(self):
         """instance method"""
         print self.a

     @classmethod
     def bb(cls):
         """class method"""
         print cls.a
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` is not defined in the scope of your `refreshStats()` function, as it is a class variable.

As such, if you want to access it, you can do `Gui.var`.

Comment: This is basically just rewording the error message without explaining *why* `var` is not defined.

Comment: @chepner hopefully more useful now