# Can anyone help me understand how to get my __str__(self) to reference my list (cList)?

Tags: python

[Code explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jVuS.png)

Here is the code I have so far.

```
value=float(input('Enter a number: '))
value2=float(input('Enter a number: '))    
value3=value+value2    
value4=float(input('Enter a number: '))    
value5=value3-value4

class sweetCurrency:   
    def  __init__(self, value):   
        self.__value = value

    def convertToList(self, value):   
        cList=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]    
        cList[0] = value//10000
        cList[1] = (value-cList[0]*10000)//5000    
        cList[2] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000)//2000    
        cList[3] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000)//1000    
        cList[4] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000)//500   
        cList[5] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500)//100    
        cList[6] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500-cList[5]*100)//25    
        cList[7] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500-cList[5]*100-cList[6]*25)//10   
        cList[8] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500-cList[5]*100-cList[6]*25-cList[7]*10)//5   
        cList[9] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500-cList[5]*100-cList[6]*25-cList[7]*10-cList[8]*5)

        print(cList)

    def __str__(self):    
        print('There are',cList[0],'hundred dollar bills',cList[1],'fifty dollar bills',cList[2],'twenty dollar bills',    
              cList[3],'ten dollar bills',cList[4],'five dollar bills',cList[5],'one dollar bills',cList[6],'quarters',   
              cList[7],'dimes',cList[8],'nickels',cList[9],'pennies')

def main():    
    FirstVal=sweetCurrency(value)    
    FirstVal.convertToList(value)   
    print(FirstVal)

    SecondVal=sweetCurrency(value3)   
    SecondVal.convertToList(value3)   
    print(SecondVal)

    ThirdVal=sweetCurrency(value5)    
    ThirdVal.convertToList(value5)

    if value4>value3:   
        print('Error: cannot be higher than last value')

    else:   
        print(ThirdVal)

main()
```

When I run the code I get NameError: cList is not defined. Sorry for any formatting issues this is my first time using this site.

Comment: use `self.cList`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python class NameError. Var is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478782/python-class-nameerror-var-is-not-defined) or even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675248/why-am-i-getting-a-nameerror-when-i-try-to-access-an-attribute-in-my-class

Answer (score 0):

You computed a `cList` in `convertToList` but did not return or save it,thus it is lost.

You should add a `self.cList = cList` to save the value and add a `cList  = self.cList` to revive it.

If you use this approach, you should also add a `self.cList=...some value...` in `__init__` or the code will break if you tried to `print` the class before calling `convertToList`.

BTW,the code can be written more campactly by using `str.format` or `%d` methods

Code:

```py
...
def convertToList(self, value):

    cList=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    cList[0] = value//10000

    cList[1] = (value-cList[0]*10000)//5000

    cList[2] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000)//2000

    cList[3] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000)//1000

    cList[4] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000)//500

    cList[5] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500)//100 

    cList[6] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500-cList[5]*100)//25

    cList[7] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500-cList[5]*100-cList[6]*25)//10

    cList[8] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500-cList[5]*100-cList[6]*25-cList[7]*10)//5

    cList[9] = (value-cList[0]*10000-cList[1]*5000-cList[2]*2000-cList[3]*1000-cList[4]*500-cList[5]*100-cList[6]*25-cList[7]*10-cList[8]*5)

    self.cList=cList

def __str__(self):

    return 'There are %d hundred dollar bills %d fifty dollar bills %d twenty dollar bills %d ten dollar bills %d five dollar bills %d one dollar bills %d quarters %d dimes %d nickels %d pennies'%tuple(self.cList)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two modifications you need to make to make this work the way you intend.

1. Replace `cList` with `self.cList`

```py
def convertToList(self, value):

        self.cList=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        self.cList[0] = value//10000
        self.cList[1] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000)//5000
        self.cList[2] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000-self.cList[1]*5000)//2000
        self.cList[3] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000-self.cList[1]*5000-self.cList[2]*2000)//1000
        self.cList[4] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000-self.cList[1]*5000-self.cList[2]*2000-self.cList[3]*1000)//500
        self.cList[5] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000-self.cList[1]*5000-self.cList[2]*2000-self.cList[3]*1000-self.cList[4]*500)//100 
        self.cList[6] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000-self.cList[1]*5000-self.cList[2]*2000-self.cList[3]*1000-self.cList[4]*500-self.cList[5]*100)//25
        self.cList[7] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000-self.cList[1]*5000-self.cList[2]*2000-self.cList[3]*1000-self.cList[4]*500-self.cList[5]*100-self.cList[6]*25)//10
        self.cList[8] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000-self.cList[1]*5000-self.cList[2]*2000-self.cList[3]*1000-self.cList[4]*500-self.cList[5]*100-self.cList[6]*25-self.cList[7]*10)//5
        self.cList[9] = (value-self.cList[0]*10000-self.cList[1]*5000-self.cList[2]*2000-self.cList[3]*1000-self.cList[4]*500-self.cList[5]*100-self.cList[6]*25-self.cList[7]*10-self.cList[8]*5)
        print(self.cList)
```

This is important to ensure that `cList` is retrievable later and it "connected" to the class instance. Currently what happens is: You call `FirstVal.convertToList()` and you assume that the `cList` is calculated and stored somewhere. But it actually is only calculated and stored within the scope of that method! Once you leave the scope of the `convertToList()` method, the `cList` is destroyed. To prevent that (assuming you need these values), you would need to reassign them to an attribute of the instance, i.e. to `self.cList`. These then become part of the `FirstVal`, `SecondVal`... instances and you can refer to them in other methods called after (e.g. in `print(FirstVal)`).

2. Ensure that `def __str__(self):` returns and not just prints a string (and also rename all `cList` references to `self.cList`:

```py
 def __str__(self):
        return f'There are {self.cList[0]} hundred dollar bills {self.cList[1]} fifty dollar bills' +\
               f'{self.cList[2]} twenty dollar bills {self.cList[3]} ten dollar bills {self.cList[4]}' +\
               f'five dollar bills {self.cList[5]} one dollar bills {self.cList[6]} quarters' +\
               f'{self.cList[7]} dimes {self.cList[8]} nickels {self.cList[9]} pennies'
```

(I added the `f''` string formatting just as an example, but you could also use the `+` operator to construct *a single string* to return).

You can see more examples of how to use `__str__` and `__repr__` on a class [here](https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions).